# Is there somebody who uses Git as repo for Nintex Workflows?

Tags: git, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

Are there any advantages using a repo like git for exported .nwf (Nintex Workflow Files)?
Currently discussing this topic, but I can't figure out any advantages besides the central repository, for example when you have a workflow which is used in different sites.
In that case .nwf files would be stored in different site collections.

Is anybody using Git (or other vendors) as repository?
Would like to here also your opinions about advantages for using a repo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using GitHub for my generic scripts right now, and I've also been toying with the idea of storing Nintex Workflow and Forms files there as well. I agree, I don't see a ton of advantage to it, aside from perhaps seeing the exact changes from version to version with each commit, but since Nintex already has versioning, I'd probably look at that rather than dig through the code.

It's something I'm still discussing with our team though. Let me know if you come across any major advantages.